# Как преобразовать обычный url в активную ссылку?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!
Как преобразовать обычный url в активную ссылку? Есть поле ввода текста, нужно чтобы строка адреса страницы  типа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php/ преобразовывалась  в `<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php/" target="_blank">https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php/</a>`

Comment: она когда должна преобразоваться? во время ввода, после него, после того как форму отправили?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да тыщи таких "преобразователей", только нет ни одного, который бы на 100% распознавал всё и корректно :-) Самые общие соображения:

1. Не стоит и браться за строки без
       протокола, будет очень много ложных
       "ссылок"
2. После протокола (говорим пока только
       о http(s) и ftp, например, всякую экзотику не
       трогаем) должны идти как минимум две
       цифробуквы, после которых - точка и
       ещё от 2 до 6 букв (национальные
       домены тоже не трогаем) - здесь можно вообще зафигачить проверку повсему списку TLD
3. И дальше начинается творчество :) Допустим, порт мы проверять не будем, query string опустим, хэши тоже. Всё равно остаётся проблема последнего символа (то есть если что-то заканчивается на точку, запятую, скобку и т.д. - будем ли мы считать это частью URL?)... И т.д.

В общем, самый тупой базовый вариант, от которого можно плясать дальше (схематично):

```
^http:\/\/[a-z_\-0-9]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,6}\/?\S*$
```

Где вместо последнего \S* и должно быть творчество. (и это не заморачиваясь с тем, что между протоколом и TLD). Вот, например, как [народ извращается](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=url)...

Можно ещё по исходникам разных форумов посмотреть, у кого как сделано, искать функции/методы с именами типа make_clickable или что-то вроде того.

Или вот пример из [FormValidator::Lite::Constraint::URL](http://search.cpan.org/~tokuhirom/FormValidator-Lite-0.31/lib/FormValidator/Lite/Constraint/URL.pm):

```
rule 'HTTP_URL' => sub 
{
    $_ =~ /^s?https?:\/\/[-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z0-9;\/?:\@&=+\$,%#]+$/
};
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду творить:)